# USB Flash drive not mounting (shows up in diskutil)

Tags: disk-utility, usb, partition, external-disk

My 16 GB USB flash drive works perfectly on Windows and Ubuntu OS. On plugging into my Macbook Pro, I don't see it fully mounted.
On running

```
$ diskutil list
```

I see the following output

```
/dev/disk5 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *15.4 GB    disk5
   1:        Apple_partition_map ⁨⁩                        4.1 KB     disk5s1
                    (free space)                         2.5 GB     -
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨⁩                        2.5 MB     disk5s2
```

[edit below]

```
$ diskutil info disk5
   Device Identifier:         disk5
   Device Node:               /dev/disk5
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk5
   Device / Media Name:       Ultra

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       Apple_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported

   Disk Size:                 15.4 GB (15376000000 Bytes) (exactly 30031250 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Removable
   Media Removal:             Software-Activated

   Solid State:               Info not available
   Virtual:                   No
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

[Edit #2]
**Solved:**

Creating a new partition table using a partition manager solved the problem. (I used KDE Partition Manager in Arch Linux)

Comment: Is this correct?  You have a 16GB drive formatting with an Apple partition scheme and it can be read in Windows and Linux but *not* Apple?  How was this drive created?  Can you add the output of `diskutil info disk5` with an [edit]?

Comment: Hi @Allan  I had formatted the USB drive on my Windows PC using Disk Management utility and it worked fine. Once I plugged it into my Mac I saw the error "The disk you attached was not readable by this computer"

Comment: I can't speak to how MS Disk Management formatted an Apple partition scheme, but I would back things up on your Windows/Linux box, then reformat it on macOS using a FAT32 file system for reliable compatibility.  I've had excellent success with that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new partition table using a partition manager solved the problem. (I used KDE Partition Manager in Arch Linux)

Answer (score 2):

### The Short Answer

You probably can fix your problem by entering the command below. To understand what *"probably"* means, you would probably need to read the rest of this answer.

```
dd if=/dev/zero count=1 seek=1 of=/dev/disk5
```

### The Long Answer

A drive can contain both a Master Boot Record (MBR) scheme and an Apple Partition Map (APM) scheme simultaneously. When this happens, Windows (and PC firmware) will choose the MBR scheme and ignore the APM scheme. On the other hand, macOS/OS X (and Intel Mac firmware) does the opposite and chooses the APM scheme over the MBR scheme.

Usually, when both schemes are deliberately applied to the same drive, this is done in a way where conflicts are avoided. Since the volume contained by the partition of type `Apple_HFS` is not mounting, you probably have a conflict which resulted in the volume at least being partially corrupted.

Below is an example using 2013 iMac running Catalina and a HP PC running Windows 11.

I started by plugging a 16 GB flash drive into the Mac and then used the Disk Utility to erase the flash drive. The following was chosen.

[image]

Next, I ejected and plug the flash drive into the PC. Windows Disk Management shown this flash drive to be `Disk 1`, as seen below.

[image]

I delete the volume shown and creating a new volume using the default size. The following was chosen.

[image]

The result is shown below.

[image]

Next, I copied a file named `scratch.txt` to the flash drive. This file is sufficiently large enough to at least overwrite the header of the JHFS+ volume named `MyJHFS+`. The result is shown below.

[image]

I ejected and returned the flash drive to the Mac. Below is the output from the command `diskutil list external` that pertains to the flash drive. You can tell the `Apple_HFS` type volume did not mount, because the name `MyJHFS+` is missing.

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *15.9 GB    disk4
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS                         15.7 GB    disk4s3
```

Below is the output from the command `sudo fdisk /dev/disk4`. This output shows the MBR Partition Table which is stored in sector 0 and was created by Windows 11.

```
Disk: /dev/disk4    geometry: 1929/255/63 [30998528 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 0C    0  32  33 - 1023 254  63 [      2048 -   30994432] Win95 FAT32L
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Note that sectors 1 through 2047 are unallocated. Typically, this is done to reserve space required for a legacy GRUB install.

Below is the output from the command `sudo pdisk -l /dev/disk4`. This output shows the APM which is stored in sectors 1 through 63 and was created by macOS Catalina.

```
Partition map (with 512 byte blocks) on '/dev/disk4'
 #:                type name     length   base     ( size )
 1: Apple_partition_map Apple        63 @ 1       
 2:          Apple_Free          262144 @ 64       (128.0M)
 3:           Apple_HFS        30736304 @ 262208   ( 14.7G)
 4:          Apple_Free              16 @ 30998512

Device block size=512, Number of Blocks=30998528 (14.8G)
DeviceType=0x0, DeviceId=0x0
```

The table below summarizes the locations of the partition tables and volumes. Note that the locations of the partition tables are not in conflict, but the volumes defined in these tables definitely are.

| Use | Type | Name | Start Sector | End Sector | Size in Secors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MBR Partition Table | FDisk_partition_scheme |  | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| APM Table | Apple_partition_map |  | 1 | 63 | 63 |
| FAT32 Volume | Windows_FAT_32 | MYFAT32 | 2048 | 30996479 | 30994432 |
| Mac OS Extended (Journaled) Volume | Apple_HFS | MyJHFS+ | 262208 | 30998511 | 30736304 |

Since the `MyJHFS+` volume failed to mount, the `MYFAT32` volume was not be damaged by macOS. Therefore zeroing out the APM table would result in macOS using the MBR partition table. Actually, zeroing out the first sector would be sufficient. This can be done by using the command given below.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero count=1 seek=1 of=/dev/disk4
```

Below is the new output from the command `diskutil list external` that pertains to the flash drive. This was observed after entering the above command.

```
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *15.9 GB    disk4
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 MYFAT32                 15.9 GB    disk4s1
```

Below is a Finder view of the mounted FAT32 volume named `MYFAT32`.
[image]

### How to Prevent Two Partition Tables

Simply use the Windows `diskpart` command to clean the drive before using Windows Disk Management. See the example shown below.

```
C:\Users\david>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22621.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: HPWINDOWS11

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB   256 GB        *
  Disk 1    Online           14 GB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> exit
```

Note: The `clean` command does remove all volumes on the drive.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The dd command didn't help remove the data. However, creating a new partition table helped! +1